# SyntaxError: missing formal parameter Firefox

Tags: javascript

This is my code it doesn't work in Firefox. It shows me SyntaxError: missing formal parameter. I don't know why. Where is the problem. It's working in Chrome

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".button", function('click') {
    var last_id = $(".button").val();
    var tagg_id = event.target.id;
    $(".button").html("Loading...");

    $.ajax({
      url: "loadData.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        last_id: last_id,
        tagg_id: tagg_id
      },
      dataType: "text",
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != "") {
          $(".button").remove();
          $("#last").append(data);
        } else {
          $(".button").html("No more posts");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: When I [run that code](http://jsbin.com/qoraxexoro/1/edit?js,console) in Chrome is says: `SyntaxError: Unexpected string`. You need to provide a real [mcve].

Comment: There is no PHP in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".button", function(event) {
```

Or with better and cleaner selector:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").on("click", function(event) {
```

You should read jQuery API documentation for better explain: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I tried your way but in firefox is showing -  'ReferenceError: event is not defined'

Comment: Edited my answer that add `event` variable to function. Thanks for downvote :D

Comment: Thank you for the answer i didn't vote down i voted up. Thank you very much